# Como puedo obtener el nombre del contacto de las bandejas de SMS

Tags: android, android-studio, sms

estoy desarrollando una aplicación que accede al historial de mensajes (SMS) en la bandeja de entrada y salida. Lo que sucede es que puedo obtener datos como la fecha o el tipo de mensaje (enviado, recibido) pero NO he logrado que se haga referencia al NOMBRE del contacto que realizó alguna de estas acciones.

Aquí el código con el que obtengo la bandeja de salida:

```
private void Cargando() {
    Uri callUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(callUri, null, null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.DATE);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.TYPE);

    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String fecha = (String) DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yy k:mm",managedCursor.getLong(date));
        String tipo = managedCursor.getString(type);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phNumber + fecha + tipo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer otra consulta al `Context#getContentResolver` con el numero de telefono:

```
public String obtenerNombreContacto(Context context, String telefono) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(telefono));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,
            new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String nombre= null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        nombre= cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return nombre;
}
```

Tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
private void Cargando() {
    Uri callUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(callUri, null, null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.DATE);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.TYPE);

    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String fecha = (String) DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yy k:mm",managedCursor.getLong(date));
        String tipo = managedCursor.getString(type);

        // buscamos el nombre del contacto
        String nombreContacto =  obtenerNombreContacto(getApplicationContext(), phNumber);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phNumber + fecha + tipo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Amigo, me podrías guiar un poco, en como llegar de mi función que consulta mensajes a incluir esto con los nombres, por favor, te lo agradecería.

Comment: Mira la respuesta actulizada y dime si eso es lo que esperas.